# JS - querySelector vs getElementsByClassName scope

Tags: javascript

I am doing a basic todo list with JavaScript/Html. I am able to add new items to my todo lists. New items are added into a `ul` as `li` and every `li` is composed of a `span` with the actual todo and a `i .remove` to remove the item from the list.

I was able to add new items to my list but I had an issue to delete items. I declared a variable at the top of my JS file to select the `.delete` i to add an `EventListener` on every icons when the user will click on the `.delete`. This is the var : `var removeToDoTwo = document.querySelector(".delete");`

However, the length of `removeToDoTwo` never updated and was always the same. I tried to use `getElementsByClassName` instead and it works, it updated the lenght of the variable every time I added a new item. What is the issue with `QuerySelector`? I thought it provided better results than the `ElementsByClassName`?

**JS**

```js
const addTodo = document.querySelector(".add");
const fullList = document.querySelector("ul");

//update
var removeToDo = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");

//never update
var removeToDoTwo = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");

addTodo.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newItem = addTodo.querySelector("input").value;
  var item = `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <span>${newItem}</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
        </li>`;
  fullList.innerHTML += item;
  addTodo.querySelector("input").value = "";
  console.log(removeToDo.length);
});
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <div class="container">

    <header class="text-center text-light my-4">
      <h1 class="mb-4">To-Do List</h1>
      <form action="" class="search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control m-auto">
      </form>
    </header>

    <ul class="list-group todos mx-auto text-light">
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <span>Eat</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <span>Drink</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form action="" class="add text-center my-4">
      <label class="text-light" for="">Add a new todo...</label>
      <input class="form-control m-auto" type="text" name="add" />
    </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: are you re-rendering the page once the changes are made? Also, can you post your delete function? there is only an "add" function above

Comment: Well querySelector returns one item, not a bunch of items. querySelectorAll is a static NodeList.

Comment: I haven't implemented deleted yet since the length of  `removeToDo`did not matched the total number of elements but now it is by using `getElementsByClassName` instead of `QuerySelector`